# Pull refresh does not update the list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

My card does not get the latest data from firestore even with pull refresh implemented in quasar

```
<q-pull-to-refresh @refresh="refresh">
  <q-card
    class="q-ma-md"
    bordered
    v-for="announcement in announcements"
    :key="announcement.key"
  >
    <q-card-section>
      <div class="text-h6">{{announcement.TITLE}}</div>
      <div class="text-subtitle2">{{announcement.CONTENT}}</div>
    </q-card-section>
  </q-card>
</q-pull-to-refresh>
```

here is my script and methods

```
data() {
return {
  announcements: [],
  };
},

 //methods
retrieveAnnouncements() {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("announcement")
    .get()
    .then(snapShot => {
      snapShot.forEach(element => {
        const { TITLE, CONTENT, AUTHOR } = element.data();
        //add retrieved data in announcement
        this.announcements.push({
          key: element.id,
          TITLE,
          CONTENT,
          AUTHOR
        });
      });
    });
},
```

here is my refresh method that tries to update the card of the current page

```
refresh(done) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    (this.announcements = null), done();
  }, 1000);
}, 
created() {
    this.retrieveAnnouncements();
}
```

Comment: I know how to do it in JS but not Quasar.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `refresh` function call `retrieveAnnouncements`?
It looks like it's only called on `created`

Comment: Hi, slr, it doesn't. Does it need to be called in refresh method?

Comment: Yeah, it should. You can return the promise from firebase in `retrieveAnnouncements` and call done once the promise resolves.

Comment: Hi, can you show me some example of how I can do it?